# How can I capture the SOAP request generated on localhost?

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, soap

I have a simple windows console app that I have added a service reference to and I am trying to call a method and make a request! I am using the proxy classes generated by .Net when I added the service reference.

The web service is not on my machine but externally hosted by the client!

I am getting an error so I would like to see the HTTP request that is being sent.

I can't see the request on fiddler, why not?

Can I seen the generated request by debugging the console app?

Comment: It would be helpful to at least specify the error you're seeing. If you're not seeing the request in fiddler, it's possible that the service call is failing even before the request is generated. Is there anything in the Event Viewer?

Comment: I am receiving HTML in the response which i suspect is an error page from the service!

Comment: Also, what are you using to generate your request? WCF?

Comment: In that scenario I'd expect the HTML to be an error message page with some info on it, and for there to be some error logged in the Event Viewer by your service giving you a clue as to what's up with your request. If you're using WCF.

Comment: razlebe, it's not my web service I am trying to hit!

Comment: @Rigobert Song Well, that complicates matters. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see localhost traffic with Fiddler. See [this article](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/hookup.asp#Q-LocalTraffic) in the Fiddler FAQ.

You could also turn on [WCF Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Fiddler bypass local traffic. If you want to sniff local address in the client config set .localhost address (with dot prefix).

Answer (score 0):

Aside of Fiddler and embedded tracing tool there is another approach to see generated XML SOAP - [**custom MessageEncoder**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.channels.messageencoder). It allows to interceprt original byte content including any malformed xml.

In order to implement tracing using this approach you need to wrap a standard [textMessageEncoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/wcf/textmessageencoding) with [custom message encoder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/custom-message-encoder-custom-text-encoder) as new [binding element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.textmessageencodingbindingelement%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and apply that custom binding to endpoint in your [config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/custom-binding-transport-and-encoding).

Also you can see as example how I did it in my project -
[wrapping](https://github.com/capslocky/WcfSoapLogger/blob/master/src/Library/WcfSoapLogger/EncodingExtension/LoggingBindingElement.cs) textMessageEncoding, logging [encoder](https://github.com/capslocky/WcfSoapLogger/blob/master/src/Library/WcfSoapLogger/EncodingExtension/LoggingEncoder.cs), custom binding [element](https://github.com/capslocky/WcfSoapLogger/blob/master/src/Library/WcfSoapLogger/EncodingExtension/LoggingExtensionElement.cs) and [config](https://github.com/capslocky/WcfSoapLogger/blob/master/src/UsageExamples/ExampleBeta/Client/App.config).